Noise Removal for Consistent Anomaly Detection in Multi-Dimensional Time Series Using Matrix Profile
In an online anomaly detection task involving multiple time series, I compute the left matrix profile using non-normalized Euclidean distances for each of the time series (Figure 1). However, since each time series has a different level of noise, the scales of the computed matrix profiles differ (See Figure 2), necessitating different decision thresholds for each sequence.
In Matrix Profile XXVIII: Discovering Multi-Dimensional Time Series Anomalies with K of N Anomaly Detection, Section 5.3 addresses this issue by suggesting subtracting the 75th percentile from distances or applying smoothing:

if data is noisy, all the distances will generally
become higher. We can remove this added base value to all
distances in Matrix Profile before calculating the KDPs to
suppress the high anomaly score caused by the noise. We
estimate this base value by calculating the 75th percentile of the
distances in Matrix Profile. This is a very intuitive parameter.
We could also achieve essentially the same result just by
smoothing the time series, before computing the Matrix Profile.

My question is, if I were to apply the subtraction of the 75th percentile, does it imply that the method will function effectively in a general case with a single threshold for all sequences? Alternatively, if I were to apply smoothing, how should I determine the level of smoothing to ensure that noise is adequately equalized, given that the original sequences may have varying levels of noise? Overall, what would be the most effective method for removing noise from a sequence so that the matrix profile can perform well in a general case with a single threshold for all sequences?

Figure 1


Figure 2


inventor of the Matrix Profile here.
Are you really sure you want to use "non-normalized Euclidean distance"?
If you don't normalize, then the differences in means dwarf the differences in shape.
In other words, for non-normalized data ED(A,B) ~= ED(mean(A),mean(B)) *sqrt(m)
That implies that the "shape" of the time series does not matter.
If that is what you want, there are easer ways to compute this.
It is VERY rare that "non-normalized" Euclidean distance or DTW has any really meaning.
If you are stuck, email me.
PS in the above 'm' is length of subsequence
